# Running tests in cypress

Tags: automation, automated-tests, cypress

I want to test a simple page to get the first available flight price.
So I chose 1st available date, then 2nd random date.
I wrote a test in cypress, it selects both dates but with the 2nd date, even when it has a step to .click(), that doesn't reflect in the calendar, it still looks selected but not clicked.

So here is the test, I know it looks simple. I'm only learning Cypress tool.

```
describe('Derive an airplane ticket prices from the calendar', () => {
    it('Should be able to open the webpage', () => {
        // cy.intercept('POST', 'https://www.mczbf.com/12706/pageInfo', {
        //     statusCode: 200,
        //     body: '',
        //     headers: {
        //         'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
        //     },
        // }).as('stubCrossOriginScript');

        cy.visit('https://airmalta.com/en');
        // cy.wait('@stubCrossOriginScript');
        cy.get('#onetrust-accept-btn-handler').click()

        //Click on `Departing from` option box:
        cy.get('.route-selection-origin > .input-holder > .form-control').click()
        cy.get('.input-drop-container > :nth-child(6)').contains('Vienna International').click()

        //Click on `Flying to` option box:
        cy.get('.route-selection-destination > .input-holder > .form-control').click()
        cy.get('.input-drop-container > :nth-child(2)').contains('Malta International Airport').click()

        //Select Departure date:
        cy.get("input[placeholder='dd/mm'][name='DepartureDate1']").click()


        cy.get('.DayPicker-Body') // Select the parent element
            .find('.DayPicker-Day[aria-disabled="false"]') // Find the day elements with aria-disabled="false"
            .first() // Select the first available date
            .click(); // Click on the first available date

        //*** To do later: assertoon for selected Departure date//

        // //Select Return date:
        cy.get("input[placeholder='dd/mm'][name='DepartureDate2']").click()
        cy.get('.DayPicker-Body')
            .find('.DayPicker-Day[aria-disabled="false"]:not([aria-selected="true"])') // Find the available dates not selected
            .then($dates => {
                const randomIndex = Cypress._.random(0, $dates.length - 1); // Generate a random index
                cy.wrap($dates[randomIndex]).click(); // Click on the randomly selected date
            });

        //*** To do later: assertoon for selected Return date//

        cy.get("button[class='btn btn-primary btn-lg d-none d-md-block']").click()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UACBR.png)

Comment: I'm confused about what the issue is here - in your image, the item appears to be clicked, and the log shows that it was clicked.

Comment: I'm sorry, I inserted a new screenshot. It's highlighted in yellow that the `Return` box doesn't have the selected date. In the test, cypress clicks on `Departure` (selects 1st available date) then clicks on `Return` and chooses a random date and clicks on it. I don't why but the chosen date for `Return` doesn't show up. So I can't proceed to another action to click on the `Find flights` button.